# Android widget issue on Lollipop 5.1 when updating the app from a previous version

Tags: android, android-widget, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an issue with an app's widget not being displayed when I update from a previous version. The widget is working fine on all devices and Android OS versions so far, except Lollipop 5.1(a Nexus 5 device).

The funny thing is if I have a debug build on the phone, see the "Problem loading widget" error and run a new build without modifying anything in the code, the widget gets back to normal.

The problem is that this affects release builds as well.

[EDIT]: Forgot to mention, but LogCat is not displaying any errors, the views used in the xml files are the ones required in the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) (makes sense as the widget is functional in every case except this one)

Does this ring any bell to anyone?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on my dev. Nexus 5. Widget is perfectly fine and operational, but after the upgrade 'sometimes' I can't add widget, no error in error log.

Comment: any way to solve the mention problem?!